# Is there a port of the Rhino JavaScript engine for .NET

Tags: .net, javascript-engine

I worked for a company that had both Java and .NET implementations of an application. The app allowed for end-user customization of processing and business rules using scripts. The Java version supported JavaScript using the [Rhino engine](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). The .NET app required VBScript. I would like to do something similar using .NET, but I would prefer to use JavaScript. I have searched but I am having a hard time finding anything like Rhino that will work within the .NET runtime. Do any of you know of or have experience using a JavaScript engine in .NET?

Comment: See also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926788/javascript-engine-with-good-interoperability-with-jvm-and-clr

Comment: Bit late, but see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744105/parse-and-execute-js-by-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98.aspx) - Microsoft's implementation of JavaScript, which is a full .NET language.

EDIT: it turns out the question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net-c). Some specific suggestions: use [Managed JScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/jscript/archive/2007/05/07/introducing-managed-jscript.aspx), or use [MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/articles/DotNetScripting.aspx) in JScript mode.

Comment: What would I use to interpret the JScript? I'm looking for a .NET library that could take the script and interpret it on the server to allow end-user scripting capabilities.

Comment: @Andrew: I linked to a previous question (with answers) and to some specific possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Rhino on .NET with IKVM.NET. I did it once it was very simple; you download the jar files and you generate dlls using IKVM.NET. Then you reference the dlls as usual.

You should check Iron JS. It is a fully .NET solution running on the DLR.

V8 should work ok as well: http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/