# Invoking Java function using Javascript runing on tracemonkey, SquirrelFish extreme or V8

Tags: jakarta-ee, serverside-javascript

I wonder how can I add JS support to the Java application I'm developing.
The only thing that matter is that eventually, the JS will be able to invoke Java functions.

While searching the web, I've found that tracemonkey, SquirrelFish extreme and V8 are the best JavaScript engines and therefore I prefer using them only (and exclude Rhino).

Thanks,
Eldad.

Answer (score 0):

> While searching the web, I've found that tracemonkey, SquirrelFish extreme and V8 are the best JavaScript engines

But they're C++ with no apparent Java bindings. Rhino is the only Javascript interpreter I'm aware of that has Java bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Google V8 has 2 bindings to the JVM,
and it has been the instigator and leader in JavaScript's current performance war.

Of course, you still need to ship a large OS-specific C++ compiled extension
in your Java app.  But it does work.

For details, see my comment in:

[Javascript engine with good interoperability with JVM and CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926788/javascript-engine-with-good-interoperability-with-jvm-and-clr?rq=1)