# .Net text calculator (formula parser)

Tags: .net, calculator

I am going to implement custom server side validation of numeric user input.

All is what I nee is to be able to feed a formula to the calculator, feed parameters and get the result back.

The formula consist of basic arithmetical operation, for example like this

```
([name1] + [name2] - [name3])*1.5
```

Then it should accept parameters like

```
calculator.AddParam("name1", 12);
```

And return the result of calculation like

```
var result = calculator.Calculate();
```

Does such libriary exist for .net?

Comment: You could just use IronScheme :) (Or IronPython/Ruby/etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/) a couple times to do this pretty quickly and easily.

Comment: It's very well-written, very extensible, and evaluates >8'000'000 formulas/sec on my laptop. Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

(C# compiling code at runtime)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/matheval.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could reuse the Javascript engine that comes with Windows, as explained here: [parse and execute JS by C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744105/parse-and-execute-js-by-c)

It's quite powerful, supports 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, and does not need to be documented, as everyone knows how to write some JS statemements :-)