# How to do a string-based query against an object? (Like LINQ-string to object)

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

Here's what I'm looking for-- a way in .NET to pass in 1) an everyday .NET object/POCO 2) a string-based query to run against said object (in whatever query language) that returns the result of the query applied to the object.

I've already tried the following with no success

- Finding a way to serialize a string into a LINQ query against an object. What i can't figure out about this is why LinqPad can do it but the code they use isn't freely available.
- Using an OData library

I'm having a hard time believing that there isn't a simple (especially Linq-based) way to query objects via a string. In javascript, i could pass the object into an `eval`-ed function context therefore execute a JS string against an object.

Roslyn is off the table. I need this to work in Mono.

Ideas?

Comment: You should be able to use [*Dynamic LINQ*](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) for that.

Comment: As I understand it LinqPad compiles the code into IL using CodeDom a sort of predecessor of Roslyn.

Comment: have you looked at NHibernate?

Comment: @Quibblesome i'm not looking for an ORM, if thats what you're getting after

Comment: Nope, just that NHibernate maps to POCOs and also offers HQL queries (string based queries) you can execute against a session object. However I have no idea about serializing the LINQ (IIRC it added LINQ support v2.x). Also as its open source I'd figure it would play reasonably nice with Mono.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic LINQ sounds good. If you would prefer to use javascript you could use a script engine. See [parse and execute JS by C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744105/parse-and-execute-js-by-c-sharp)

Comment: dynamic linq would allow me to specify a where clause or an orderby clause but not necessarily an entire query against an obj, right? i'm going after the entire query

Comment: and i would rather avoid embedding a js engine if at all possible. if it gets to that i'd rather rewrite the existing code to node