# WPF dynamically create formula in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a project where the user needs to have the ability to create a formula in a `WPF` app.
The formula has to be made from some `properties`.
Let's say we have `properties`:

```
public decimal? Prop1 { get; set; }
public decimal? Prop2 { get; set; }
public decimal? Prop3 { get; set; }
```

Now, let's say we have a `TextBox` where the user has to be able to input only those `properties` and in between of the there needs to be some of the operators:
`+, -, /, *`.

I got the part where the user can only input those values `properties` and operators…
But my problem is how can I save that formula to the `SQL` `database` (lets say `Prop1` * `Prop2`), how can I get the formula from `database` and make it read the values from the and basically "do the math…"

```
decimal? x = MyFormula;
```

I know the question is difficult, and so is my description of my it… Please feel free to ask for more detail if needed, and I'll try to explain it.

Comment: You can run javascript formula in C#, just need to replace PropX placeholders with values from properies. Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744105/parse-and-execute-js-by-c-sharp for more details.

Comment: @just-my-name Yes, basically that's what I want, but I'm searching for that "replace"... That's with what I'm struggling

Comment: I've used ironpython for what sounds like a similar requirement. If it fits what you want to do it is easy to implement.   https://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/Using-IronPython-for-Dynamic-Expressions_2E00_

Answer (score 1):

There's two distinct questions there, and they're both a bit open ended.

My suggestion for your first question would be to serialise the Model / ViewModel to a string.  You might find that you want to store them slightly differently.  For example:

```
public class Property
{
    public string PropReference{get;set;}
}

public class Operator
{
    public string Operator{get;set;}
}

public class Calculation
{
    public Property Prop {get;set;}
    public Operator Op {get;set;}
    public Property Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

That way you can chain them together, and even nest them.  In answer to your second question, you might want to investigate a library such as [Jace](https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace), as this isn't an easy problem, but has already been solved.

EDIT - Alternative solution based on comments:

```
public class Operator : IAction
{
    public string Operator {get;set;}
}

public class Calculation : IAction
{
    IList<KeyValuePair<IAction, Property>> Operations {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about similar, but the difference is that there can be an > 1 operator or even none. And the calculation too, more than one Property and none or more types of Calculation

Comment: You could potentially make the Proprty/Operator a kvp list, which would easily allow chaining.  If you also need nesting you could simply reference a Calculation from within Calculation