# Can I use JSInterop to run stand alone JavaScript code in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, interop

I am looking for an engine to run stand-alone JavaScript code from my C# (WinForms) application. The idea behind it, is that the user can provide some script to describe behaviour in the application.

Looking around I can find the `JSInterop` classes, which seem to do what I want, but I fail to find a good example or even find out if it can do what I want.

So, simple question, could the `JSInterop` classes work in scenario like this:

```
var javascript = "function foo() { return 5; }";
var engine = JSInterop.SomeEngine();
var i = engine.run(javascript);

// i is 5 now
```

Comment: [ScriptEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/windows-script-engines) could be able to do that as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744105/parse-and-execute-js-by-c-sharp).

Comment: I found `Microsoft.ClearScript` as well. But I know not to ask for library advice here ;-)). I asked specifically about `JSInterop` because I am using other interop libaries already, and they are provided by Microsoft.