# Executing javascript from C#

Tags: javascript, c#

In a project, I'm handling a service written in C#, that when called, will return a generated Javascript function.
Think of it like this, but more complex:

```
string GetJSFunction(int value) {
return "function my_js_function() { return " + value.ToString() + "; }"
}
```

I want to do unit tests (in C#) to check that the methods I'm generating are valid JS code and behave correctly.
Are there any "simple" way to do this?
I've thought of doing the following:

- write the JS function to a temporary html page
- use a headless browser to call the webpage, call the JS script
- parse and check the result

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744105/parse-and-execute-js-by-c-sharp This question is a duplicate.