# Where Is Browser Javascript Stored and Executed?

Tags: javascript, memory, scripting

When javascript is run in a browser

```
alert('Hello World');
```

What environment executes it and manages it in memory?
I know this is vaugue! But thats the best place to start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This depends on the browser, The JavaScript engine, and what you mean by 'executes it'**

There is not much of an answer to give.

Look at some JavaScript engine's architectures ...

http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/

http://code.google.com/p/v8/

If you want to explore deeper, maybe read the first few chapters of the **Dragon Book** to learn a bit about how programs are interpreted and/or compiled to some intermediate or bytecode form.

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 4):

The browser's javascript engine.

[Here's a page](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-performance-rundown/) that compares the performance of a bunch

Comment: Link to an engine's c# bindings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net-c