# ASP.NET MVC - Returning JavaScriptResult doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

If I try to return some JavaScript from my Controller like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{       
    return JavaScript("alert('Hello world!');");            
}
```

I do not view the alert message in my browser, but I get a download request for a .js script from the page named as the action (register.js in my case). What is wrong?

Comment: How are you calling your action?  Also, be aware that this is generally considered an [anti-pattern](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/02/07/beware-of-asp-net-mvc-javascriptresult.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(){

return Json(new {isok=true, message="Your Message", data=...});

//True / False Json Return
//return UserObj == null ?
//Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
//Json(string.Format("YourObject '{0}' to String", YourObject),
//JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}

//view
$.ajax
{

//code
success :function(returnvalue)
{

if(!returnvalue.isok)
{
window.alert("Error:" + returnvalue.message);
}
else
{
//do the stuff with returnvalue.data
}

}
```

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem with the specified JavaScript not executing when returning the result as a `JavaScriptResult`. In my case, the JavaScript content was rendering as text inside `<pre>` tags.

The solution is to return the JavaScript as a `ContentResult`, by using the `Content()` method. So try:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{       
    return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello world!');</script>");            
}
```

I found the answer on the ASP.NET forums. Have a look at Bruce's answer at the following link for a more complete explanation of why it gets done this way:

[Return JavascriptResult Not Working](http://forums.asp.net/t/1716356.aspx/1)

Comment: thanks! this works when invoking the ActionMethod directly from Browser address bar, which is what i needed to do.

Answer (score 7):

I would not return Javascript, I would return `Content`, then on the page, I would convert that content to an alert:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{       
    return Content("Hello world!");            
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/Action/DoSomething/",
    type: "POST",
    success: editSuccess,
    error: editFailure
});

function editSuccess(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

Comment: I kown that is anti-pattern, but I need sometimes to call a defined javascript function from my controller (the alert(); was an example). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to return a js code using JavaScriptResult, keep in mind that your action should be called via ajax call. Calling this action via Html.Actionlink or other controls directly, results in showing your script text instead of running the script. So you need to add a js code in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
          $('#myButtonId').click(function () { 
                $.getScript("/MyController/DoSomething"); 
           });
    });
</script>
```

and your action in MyController:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{       
    return JavaScript("alert('Hello world!');");            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling your action from the view, make sure you use `@Ajax.ActionLink` instead of the `@Html.ActionLink` helper method. The JavaScript will then render correctly and your alert will display.