# Close Popup Windows MVC Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a popup window opened when clicked a link on screen, the view that has the link is _DetailsSurvey. After clicking the link pop up window opens with the content of _EditSurvey view. At the end of _EditSurvey, I have button

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

I am using Ajax option and after button click I insert a row into Survey table if the modelstate is valid.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitSurvey", "Blog", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
    UpdateTargetId = "context",
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    Url = "/Home/SubmitSurvey"
    },
    new { surveyItem = @Model }))
```

What i want to do is if the modelstate is valid after returning from SubmitSurvey method I want the pop up window to be closed.I use the following method to achieve this but it does not work.

```
    Employee employee;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        int employeeId = surveyItem.EmployeeId;
        int trainingId = surveyItem.TrainingId;
        employee = _work.EmployeeRepository.GetSet().
        FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == employeeId);


        var training = _work.TrainingRepository.GetSet().Where(a => a.EmployeeId == employeeId && a.Id == trainingId).ToList().ElementAt(0);
        training.Survey = surveyItem.survey;
        training.SurveyId = surveyItem.survey.Id;

       /* _work.SurveyRepository.Add(surveyItem.survey);
        _work.SurveyRepository.Save();*/
        _work.TrainingRepository.UpdateAndSave(training);
        _work.TrainingRepository.Save();

    }
    else
    {

        return PartialView("_EditSurvey", surveyItem);
    }
    return JavaScript("window.close()");
```

I create my popup links as follows

```
 <tr>
    <td class="view_detail_label">
        Eğitim Adı
    </td>
        <td>

           @Html.ActionLink(
           training.Name.Name, 
           "AddSurvey", 
           new { 
               employeeId = Model.Id, 
               trainingId = training.Id 
           },
           new {
               @class = "addSurvey"
           }
       )
         <div class="result" style="display:none;"></div>             
        </td>            
    </tr>
```

The called ajax code is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addSurvey').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                $(this).next('.result').html(result).dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title: 'Anket',
                    width: 500,
                    height: 'auto',
                    modal: true
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

In my pop up view I am using previously shown Ajax BeginForm and below that I have the table where user inputs values of the survey. At the end I have the submit button.

```
<table id="context">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.survey.Context)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.survey.Context)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.survey.Context)
        </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Kaydet" />
            </td>
    </tr>
```

I show validation message next to each field if there is any problem with the provided input. If the model was valid I want to do either close the popup window.

Comment: Javascript returned from an MVC controller? Can you even do that? And why would you? You give no feedback to the user who went to the bother of filling out the form you gave them. Use a jQuery dialog; load a partial view with your form. Validate on the client using unobtrusive valdiation and again after submit! Then return a partial view informing the user that their form has been saved. Let them close the dialog.

Comment: You can return Javascript, there were some other topics that are related but in this case it does not work. I give feedback to user when the model is not valid with validation messages for each field in the model. How can I give that the action is completed successfully in the view?

Comment: I think it's a bit of an anti pattern but anyway; try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271005/asp-net-mvc-returning-javascriptresult-doesnt-work

Comment: This does not work either I have done the samething setting the ViewBag.close as true when i return from validated model and tried to close the windows but it does not work. The provided link does not work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to open a popup window for many reasons I won't explain here. I spend a very long time to find a solution I could consider as perfect (for me).

In my case, I prepare the view as a partial one (without html, header and body). Just the necessary items do create my functionality in a div.

Then I request my partial view using an ajax query after what I feed a div with my partial view string and I apply the JQuery dialog method to the div for my view to be displayed as a floating dialog box and I bind the OK button to an ajax post to send data to the server.
If you want to have the unobstrusive validation to works, you must parse the form with the validator.

I invite you to have a look to my framework, everything you need is available.

https://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#461106

Comment: I cant seem to find in which components you are implementing my problem in which controller you bound the validation, can you explain it to me? Thank you