# mvc view jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, view

How do I call a javascript function from within razor markup in a cshtml view?  Basically I want to do something like this (which doesnt work):

Javascript file being included on the page has a method like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doesThisWork() {
return true;
}
</script>
```

View has code block similar to this:

```
<div>
@if(doesThisWork()) {
<span> this DOES work!!! </span>
}
else
{
<span> this does NOT work!!! </span>
}
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709978/call-javascript-from-mvc-controller-action

Comment: You cannot call js in html.Can you explain more about what you want to do?Maybe you can use different way to do it.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is this: Render one of two html blocks with values coming from a CMS depending on a value that's being read in from a cookie.  This has to be done on the front end so if the user adjusts their cookie setting, the appropriate html block should be swapped out without having to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the javascript function on the server side but it can be achieved as below code.

**Html:**

```
//Declare a div where you want display html
<div id="bindHtml"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  //On pageload call function and display Html based on your function return.
   $(document).ready(function(){
      let htmlContent = "";
       if(doesThisWork()){
          htmlContent = "<span> this DOES work!!! </span>";
       }else{
          htmlContent = "<span> this does NOT work!!! </span>";
       }
       //Bind Html to declared div in the Html
       $("#bindHtml").append(htmlContent);
    });

    function doesThisWork() {
       return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I specifically need to be able to check the return value of the javascript in the if then statement in razor.

Comment: `I specifically need to be able to check the return value of the javascript in the if then statement in razor`I'm afraid not.You'd better replace html with js as Ram Anugandula shown in his answer.