# .NET HTML Parser that supports Form posting

Tags: .net, html, forms, post, html-parser

I know there are libraries that are used to parse html like HTMLAgilityPack but unable to find a library that supports form posting or executing javascript.
I want to post html form from my Windows Form application but don't want to use WebBrowser control or MSHTML library.

Comment: Javascript: no, but as for POST, just read up how to construct those requests.

Comment: By saying form post I meant to submit form after filling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple solutions here because the act of creating a POST request and sending it to a server is separate from the act of parsing and executing JavaScript.

That said, if you want to create a POST request, there are multiple options in .NET, the most prominent being the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes, as well as the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class, which is a higher level wrapper around `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`.

For executing JavaScript, the assumption is that you want to execute JavaScript *in the page*, and while there are [stand-alone .NET JavaScript parsers/execution engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net-c) out there, they don't necessarily work *in the page*.

To that end, the MSHTML library (even though you said you didn't want to use it, I imagine you are on a server and have threading/COM apartment issues?) is really a good choice, and you can wrap access to it sufficiently in .NET (although not easily, depending on your needs) to allow you to do what you want.

If you are a fan of [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/), then you can use the [.NET wrapper for WebKit (WebKit.NET)](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) in your application.  Note: [there are some issues as of September 2011](http://www.whattofix.com/blog/archives/2010/09/google-chrome-a.php), which might or might not be addressed by now.