# Logging Javascript interactions with c#

Tags: c#, javascript

I was wondering if anyone might have any suggestions on how to log javascript interactions with a browser in C#. The reason behind it is I would like to design a web crawler that take note of any javascript interactions, which I would like to potentially sift through to find any sort of malicious calls of any kind.

Comment: How do you intend to do this? As a browser plugin? Because capturing JavaScript things from the server side is impossible.

Comment: This will get you started on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3182411/1232818

Answer (score 0):

You must capture what happens under the server's hood first, so you may need a logging tool like this: [jqlog](https://code.google.com/p/jqlog/)

> A logging framework plugin for jQuery that can be configured and extended allowing you to "roll your own" logging framework.

Basic usage:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.jqlog.enabled(true);
        $.jqlog.log("Log entry");
        $.jqlog.info("Information entry");
        $.jqlog.warn("Warning entry");
        $.jqlog.error("Error entry");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

After this, you can use C# or whatever your want, but you must understand what happens with your Javascript code.