# Programmatically compile typescript in C#?

Tags: c#, compilation, typescript, tsc

I'm trying to write a function in C# that takes in a string containing typescript code and returns a string containing JavaScript code. Is there a library function for this?

Comment: You could automate the command line compiler...

Comment: Could have a look at: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3182411/1344760)

Comment: @SWeko: I'm looking at `tsc` but I don't see anything that will take in TS and output JS. It only works with files as far as I can see.

Comment: @RichardTowers: Huh? What's that got to do with TypeScript? I don't see a single mention of TS.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit obtuse. The typescript compiler compiles to JavaScript, if you want to run it from C# then one approach would be to use a JS interpreter that you can run from the CLR/DLR.

Comment: Well, save to ts file -> compile to js file -> File.ReadAllText...

Comment: @RichardTowers: I don't need to run it in C#, just compile :-)

Comment: @SWeko: I need to write it to a temporary file every time I want to compile TypeScript? I'm going to be doing this a lot, I don't want to be hitting my HDD every time.

Comment: It's not a smart solution, but it's a solution. I'm very interested in a possible answer to this myself.

Comment: There's also a similar thread [in the TypeScript forums](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397810).

Comment: GitHub issues [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1226) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2118)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Process` to invoke the compiler, specify `--out file.js` to a temporary folder and read the contents of the compiled file.

I made a little app to do that:

Usage

```
TypeScriptCompiler.Compile(@"C:\tmp\test.ts");
```

To get the `JS string`

```
string javascriptSource = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\tmp\test.js");
```

Full source with example and comments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // compiles a TS file
                TypeScriptCompiler.Compile(@"C:\tmp\test.ts");

                // if no errors were found, read the contents of the compile file
                string javascriptSource = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\tmp\test.js");
            }
            catch (InvalidTypeScriptFileException ex)
            {
                // there was a compiler error, show the compiler output
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class TypeScriptCompiler
    {
        // helper class to add parameters to the compiler
        public class Options
        {
            private static Options @default;
            public static Options Default
            {
                get
                {
                    if (@default == null)
                        @default = new Options();

                    return @default;
                }
            }

            public enum Version
            {
                ES5,
                ES3,
            }

            public bool EmitComments { get; set; }
            public bool GenerateDeclaration { get; set; }
            public bool GenerateSourceMaps { get; set; }
            public string OutPath { get; set; }
            public Version TargetVersion { get; set; }

            public Options() { }

            public Options(bool emitComments = false
                , bool generateDeclaration = false
                , bool generateSourceMaps = false
                , string outPath = null
                , Version targetVersion = Version.ES5)
            {
                EmitComments = emitComments;
                GenerateDeclaration = generateDeclaration;
                GenerateSourceMaps = generateSourceMaps;
                OutPath = outPath;
                TargetVersion = targetVersion;
            }
        }

        public static void Compile(string tsPath, Options options = null)
        {
            if (options == null)
                options = Options.Default;

            var d = new Dictionary<string,string>();

            if (options.EmitComments)
                d.Add("-c", null);

            if (options.GenerateDeclaration)
                d.Add("-d", null);

            if (options.GenerateSourceMaps)
                d.Add("--sourcemap", null);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.OutPath))
                d.Add("--out", options.OutPath);

            d.Add("--target", options.TargetVersion.ToString());

            // this will invoke `tsc` passing the TS path and other
            // parameters defined in Options parameter
            Process p = new Process();

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("tsc", tsPath + " " + String.Join(" ", d.Select(o => o.Key + " " + o.Value)));

            // run without showing console windows
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;

            // redirects the compiler error output, so we can read
            // and display errors if any
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

            p.StartInfo = psi;

            p.Start();

            // reads the error output
            var msg = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            // make sure it finished executing before proceeding 
            p.WaitForExit();

            // if there were errors, throw an exception
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
                throw new InvalidTypeScriptFileException(msg);
        }
    }

    public class InvalidTypeScriptFileException : Exception
    {
        public InvalidTypeScriptFileException() : base()
        {

        }
        public InvalidTypeScriptFileException(string message) : base(message)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution, although I really wish I could keep it all in memory (input and output).

Comment: I face with a 'File not found' with a Win32Exception, but my path for my TS file is correct. I think it's tha path to the TSC compiler which is not correct. Have you faced with this issue one time ?

EDIT: I specify directly the path for my TSC compiler, now I have this message : "The specified executable is not a valid application for this operating system platform."

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could use a JavaScript interpreter like [JavaScriptDotNet](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) to run the typescript compiler [tsc.js](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2bee84410e02#bin/tsc.js) from C#.

Something like:

```
string tscJs = File.ReadAllText("tsc.js");

using (var context = new JavascriptContext())
{
    // Some trivial typescript:
    var typescriptSource = "window.alert('hello world!');";
    context.SetParameter("typescriptSource", typescriptSource);
    context.SetParameter("result", "");

    // Build some js to execute:
    string script = tscJs + @"
result = TypeScript.compile(""typescriptSource"")";

    // Execute the js
    context.Run(script);

    // Retrieve the result (which should be the compiled JS)
    var js = context.GetParameter("result");
    Assert.AreEqual(typescriptSource, js);
}
```

Obviously that code would need some serious work. If this *did* turn out to be feasible, I'd certainly be interested in the result.

You'd also probably want to modify `tsc` so that it could operate on strings in memory rather than requiring file IO.

Comment: Oh..you meant run the `tsc` compiler via JavaScriptDotNet, not the output. Still quite a roundabout way of doing it, but in theory I guess it should work...

Comment: Yep, sorry for not being clearer. It's difficult talking about three languages at once!

Answer (score 3):

The TypeScript compiler file officially runs on either node.js or Windows Script Host - it is written in TypeScript itself (and transpiled to JavaScript). It requires a script host that can access the file system.

So essentially, you can run TypeScript from any language as long as you can wrap it in a script engine that supports the file system operations required.

If you wanted to compile TypeScript to JavaScript purely in C#, you would end up writing a C# clone of the compiler.