# Cast <text> to string?

Tags: c#, razor

I essentially want to pass a multi-line string to a function from inside of a Razor/cshtml view.

I was hoping I could use `<text>` to accomplish this.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
        @Js.Tsc(@<text>
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor (message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}   

var greeter = new Greeter("world");

var button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerText = "Say Hello"
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet())
}

document.body.appendChild(button)
        </text>.ToString())
```

But I still get

> Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

on the `@Js.Tsc(@<text>` line.

I thought the `.ToString()` would have cast it properly. Is there a way to do this?

I know I can use `@"`-style strings, but that makes writing the code in between more complicated.

Comment: `@Js.Tsc` -- I think I see [where](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14046203/1344760) this is going :-p

Answer (score 1):

Razor is still C# code, so I'm thinking you would pass the script as you would any other string parameter. But you'll have to escape any special characters, such as the double quotes. And I don't think you need the `@<text>`.

```
@Js.Tsc("class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor (message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return \"Hello, \" + this.greeting;
    }
}   

var greeter = new Greeter(\"world\");

var button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerText = \"Say Hello\"
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet())
}

document.body.appendChild(button);")
```

Comment: Yes.. I commented on that in my last sentence. I was hoping to avoid having to escape all the quotes in my JS.

Comment: Can you split the script to a separate file, then pass a StreamReader to the function instead of a string? That would save the escaping task, but you'd be forced to live with a more strict development protocol.

Comment: Nope. That completely defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do here. If I had my script in a separate file I'd just run it through the normal typescript handler. I wanted to mix in some C# variables from the view I'm working in, which I can't do if it's a separate script file.

Comment: Not that I'm advocating this, just trying to find an answer that suits you, but you could come up with a token replacement convention (similar to string.Format), read the file from disk or URI, and pass the replaced string to the Tsc() method.

Comment: You mean to sub-in my C# vars? If I were to go down that route I might want to instead add some query params to the script request, e.g., `<script type="text/javascript">/myspecialscript.ts?var1=a&var2=b</script>` and then create a special request handler to process the file.

Comment: I think those may be your choices. Can't say I'm a fan of any of them.