# How to run script language in server side

Tags: .net

I am looking for a way, that developers can access my portal and write their own slim script so I can evaluate on my server.

the most complicated thing this script has to do is HTTP POST requests and get their response (in JSON).

I was thinking about JS. something like that

```
function foo(arg0, arg1)
{
    var res = doHTTP(arg0);
    return res.replace("a", arg1);
}
```

My server is .NET but I am willing to write my server in any language/script.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at running Javascript from within .NET, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net-c ?

Answer (score 0):

Do the developers have to type only JavaScript? It's also entirely possible to allow other languages such as C# or C/C++ and have them compiled server-side. If the environment is properly secured, allowing compilation and execution of C# code is viable and extremely powerful for the developers.

http://www.interviewstreet.com allows code to be written in the browser and compiled server-side. The server can also make use of the output from the programs written.