# Exécute ActionScript Form SWF Files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, flash

I have a SWF file on my C# project and I want to execute the ActionScript code in it. Anyone see a possible way to do that directly in C# ?

Best regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net

Comment: Thanks adv but the topic you link talk about JS and not Flash :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is a Windows Forms project, maybe you can use the web browser tool. Put a panel inside the form. The size and location of the panel will be the size and location of the browser. Embed the swf file in an html page and load the page from your form through the browser tool.

I should warn you that I haven't tried this.