# Sandbox JavaScript in C# Code and execute it

Tags: c#

Is it possible to sandbox a JavaScript function in C# code, execute it by passing in an argument such as an array, and return a result. No web browser involved here, this is not an Ajax or 'registerstartupscript' type of question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own experience, for simple things [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) works like a charm and it's a JavaScript that can be used to run-time compile JavaScript and call functions, variables or whatever.

For example, [taken from their own doc pages](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Evaluating%20an%20expression&referringTitle=Documentation):

```
var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
Console.WriteLine(engine.Evaluate("5 * 10 + 2"));
```

There're other options which involves embedding a full JavaScript engine, but AFAIK and reading your question's requirement, it seems like Jurassic should work in your scenario and you get the advantage of using a managed JavaScript compiler written in C# so there's no other dependency than the BCL from .NET and Jurassic itself.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, do you know if nodeService in dotnetcore can also run code in a sandbox?

Comment: @JavaadPatel I don't know that, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

JavaScript.NET is a .NET port of Google's V8 engine.

- https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net

Another one I quite like is called Jurassic and it's available on nuget.

- https://jurassic.codeplex.com/