# C# WebApplication with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-applications

I am trying to run Javascript function inside `ASP.Net` Web Application, and i am using `WebBrowser` to do this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> mainDic = (Dictionary<string, object>)js.DeserializeObject(fulljsFile);

String base64Content = (String)mainDic["html"];
String html = Base64.Base64Decode(base64Content);

Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
{
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();

    browser.Navigate("about:blank");
    if (browser.Document != null)
    {
        browser.Document.Write(string.Empty);
    }

    browser.Document.Write(html);

    string name = (string)browser.Document.InvokeScript("extract");
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

This is the `html` var :

```
<html><script>
function extract()
{
    return 'Steve';
};
    </script>
</html>
```

The problem is that `name` is empty instead of `Steve`.

When i run it locally on my `IIS` server it's working, but when i upload it to my server it's fail to return something to `name` var.

Comment: @CodeCaster I need to run JavaScript function in the code

Comment: There are better ways to do that, see for example [Embedding JavaScript engine into .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net). Anyway non-repro, this code does not "return" anything. Please show your actual code, and the exception handling you use. I'm fairly sure WinForms's WebBrowser doesn't like to be run on a server, as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering if the document has loaded into the browser at the point that you try and run the script.
So, can you try handling the navigation complete event and run the script from there instead.

Comment: When i am trying to get the WebBrowser source code i get it