# C# Server validation for Google Maps API - calculate area of rectangle

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Javascript Goole Maps API in my web application. The user draws a rectangles and then I am calculation the area of his rectangle using:

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(coordinates)
```

The area and the coordinates are send to the server, but in order to prevent hacking I need to recalculate on the server the area based on the coordinates received. I need to use the same formula for area calculation of area, but I have no access to Google Maps API area calculation formula. This is why my result using any formula found on the internet is different from their result, which is more accurate.

So, I am looking for a solution to calculate in C# the area of a Google Maps rectangle using their formula, which I can only use in Javascript.
None of the C# API's for Google Maps that I have found, offer the solution for area calculus.

Could you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try to Embed JavaScript engine into .NET - http://stackoverflow.com/q/172753/1023562

Comment: yes I think that this might be a solution