# How to read a string from a Website using C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I've used `WebClient` class in C# and tried the following code to get a text file from a PHP script generating a Json script. I need to read this in C#. The following code is used:

```
var client = new WebClient();
String text = client.DownloadString("http://healthmonitor.epizy.com/getHistory.php?start=20181113100504&ending=20181113103453");
textBox5.Text = text;
```

The output was this:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("7a3810cb30970e29869e0e75c85f0a7e");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://healthmonitor.epizy.com/getHistory.php?start=20181114200744&ending=20181114200744&i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

The expecting result is a Json in text from as you can simply check this: http://healthmonitor.epizy.com/getHistory.php?start=20181113100504&ending=20181113103453

Much appreciate if someone can help me to sort this out.

Thanking You in advance!

Comment: SO what has the PHP tag got to do with this question?

Comment: The Json is echoed from the database to the page using a PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error, because the website is using JavaScript. But your client (= your c# program), does not support JavaScript like a browser does.

It says so at the end of the HTML response:

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
>   your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

Comment: Thank you @Erik Kalkoken for the response. Is there anyways I can get the text from http://healthmonitor.epizy.com/getHistory.php?start=20181113100504&ending=20181113103453

Comment: You could use selenium with a headless chrome browser to browse to the site, from there you should be able to extract the DOM as a string.

Comment: I think you need to add a JavaScript engine to your app that is able to interpret the JS code that is embedded in the PHP script. This answer seams to provide some good enigines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net